# Dictionary of dictionary values in a nested for loop

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, for-loop

I have the following code where I would like to create a dictionary which stores the differences between other dictionaries.

```
for j in range(0,15):
    for k in range(0,15):
        dvarz[k] = vz[j] - vz[k]
        dvarrx[k] = vrx[j] - vrx[k]
    allz[j] = dvarz
    allrx[j] = dvarrx
```

This makes `allz` and `allrx` to be the last values of `dvarz` and `dvarrx`. So `allz` and `allrx` become the same values repeated 15 times.

Sorry for the misunderstanding. Here is a more general case with the same problem only with a list.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [3, 4, 5]
c = {}
d = {}
for i in range(0,3):
    for j in range(0,3):
       c[j] = a[i] - b[j]
    d[i] = c
```

In this case I would like d to be [[a[0] - b[0], a[0] - b[1]...], [a[1] - b[0]...]...]

Comment: What’s your *question*? Could you give a [mcve] with more useful names?

Comment: What do you want them to contain? You're just doing a reference copy, so it makes sense to see the result you get. If you want to store the values of those lists _at that iteration_ only, you'll want to make a shallow copy with `x[j] = y.copy()`

Comment: Perhaps you want `allz[j] = dvarz.copy()` and `allrx[j] = dvarrx.copy()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create new dictionaries on the fly to store differences of other dictionaries much more efficiently using a dictionary comprehension

```
a = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}

b = {'a':1, 'b':0, 'c':5}

diff = {x:a[x] - b[x] for x in a}
```